MacOS terminal command how to use ping -I
I'm trying to run a ping test using Terminal on a Mac connected to an external streaming device.
No problem with Terminal talking to the device via ssh, but then hit a problem because the default interface on the device is for management functions and doesn't reach the outside world.
The valid interface on the device is named mtpp0
I'm told this works in non-Mac environment:
# ping -I mtpp0 www.blah.com
PING www.blah.com (__.___.___.93)

But it fails when I try above on a Mac Terminal.
Helpfully, Terminal lists -I as:

-I IFACE/IP Source interface or IP address

I've tried:
xxxx@xxxxx_ng:~$ ping -I mtpp0 XXX.XXX.XXX.110
PING XXX.XXX.XXX.110 (XXX.XXX.XXX.110): 56 data bytes
^C
--- XXX.XXX.XXX.110 ping statistics ---
56 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
xxxx@xxxxx_ng:~$

any ideas? thanks
